# angularJs form not adding object to array properly. 2 way binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have started a demo app and come across this problem where my parts that I am adding to the repairs are not being properly proccessed. This is my first angular that I am building.

To get the bug press update on one of the repair cards and then scroll down to the quantity and repair item section at the bottom of the form and try to add a new item. it doesnt regester what is in the form.

[This is the codepen with the full view that doesnt work.](http://codepen.io/batsauto/pen/egBmeM?editors=1010)

This is the function in the controller to pass the info the factory.

```
$scope.addPartsPerRepair = function() {
    partFactory.addPartsPerRepair($scope.newPartsPerRepair);
    $scope.newPartsPerRepair = {};
};
```

This is the function in the factory to add the new repair to the array partsPerRepair

```
factory.addPartsPerRepair = function(newPartsPerRepair) {
partsPerRepairs.push(newPartsPerRepair);
};
```

After I abstracted away the repair factory and simplified my view we are left with this

[This is the codepen with the partial view that does work.](http://codepen.io/batsauto/pen/XpNbav?editors=1010)

I have been over this code for the past 6 hours trying to fix this one probelm and I can not see my issue.

Secondly, This is more of an add-on question, Does anyone have any advice on how to save the partsPerRepair to the actual repair[Idx] instead of in one array called partsPerRepair that every repair accesses. I thought I might be able to add an array called parts to each repair and store quanity and item name in that array but that has proven to be more difficult then I can manage. I realize I am asking two different questions but since your here reading I figured you might be willing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you are describing.  The codepen you posted that "doesnt work" seems to add parts, save them, and continue to show them without any issue.  However, it seems like you do have something wrong, as both repairs seem to be sharing the same item list....

Comment: Yes that is question two of my post. That is funny because I have tried it several times more and when i click add a part all i see blank fields being populated and then a delete button.

Comment: *I realize I am asking two different questions but since your[sic] here reading I figured you might be willing.* Please limit yourself to one question per question. Also, please include the code you are asking about, boiled down to a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dibdab/pen/mROprZ).

So I've tried to resolve both your questions here, but all I have edited is the arra yof repairs and the add parts method, which means there is alot of cleaning up chanegs to be made like deleting the old `partsPerRepairs` and its references.

- First thing `newPartsPerRepair` needed to be intialized this is why add parts was not working the function was passsing `undefined`(anything used as model in `ng-model` needs to be intialized), which is done in the controller - `$scope.newPartsPerRepair = {};`.
- Second I moved the `partsPerRepairs` array into the `repairs` array and called it `parts` this is under each customer in the array, this is to answer your second question.
- Third I changed the way the `ng-repeats` work to use these new `parts` arrays - `ng-repeat="partsPerRepair in repairs[$index].parts track by $index"`
- Finally I moved and edited the `addNewParts` to the repairs factory so it used the new parts array and could access the repairs array.

Hope this all helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my code. It really has helped and is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again.